# mongodb, mongoosejs return document and only certain subdocuments/fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema:

```
{
    user: { type: String, required: true },
    pass: { type: String, required: true },
    tokens: [String],
    book: {
        cards: [{
            id: String,
            copies: Number
        }],
        groups: [String],
        users: [String],
        orgs: [String],
        stats: {

        }
    },
    decks: [{
        name: String,
        description: String,
        cards: [{
            id: String,
            copies: Number
        }],
        groups: [String],
        users: [String],
        orgs: [String],
        stats: {

        }
    }],
    groups: [String],
    orgs: [String]
}
```

I have two supplied parameters: 'user' and 'access_user', the array `schema.book.users[]` may or may not contain 'access_user'. The array `schema.decks[i].users[]` may or may not contain 'access_user'. eg:

```
{
    user: 'bob',
    pass: 'secret',
    tokens: ['8ht490g'],
    book: {
        cards: [...],
        groups: [...],
        users: ['NOPE'],
        orgs: [...],
        stats: {
            ...
        }
    },
    decks: [{
        name: 'deck1',
        description: ...,
        cards: [...],
        groups: [...],
        users: ['access_user'],
        orgs: [...],
        stats: {
            ...
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'deck2',
        description: ...,
        cards: [...],
        groups: [...],
        users: ['NOPE'],
        orgs: [...],
        stats: {
            ...
        }
    }],
    groups: [...],
    orgs: [...]
}
```

With the compare user 'bob' 'access_user'.

I want this in return:

```
{
    user: 'bob',
    decks: [{
        name: 'deck1',
        description: ...,
        cards: [...]
    }]
}
```

I tried a few things, nothing seems to be working. `model.find()` will not work what I need is complex enough. Aggregation is really the only way. I am just not sure how to build it.

This is what I was trying:

```
model.aggregate([
    { $match: { user: 'bob' } },
    { $project: {
        'book.users': { $match: 'access_user' }
    }},
    { $project: {
        'decks.users': { $match: 'access_user' }
    }}
]);
```

I am pretty sure none of this is correct, but, I do not fully understand MongoDB's aggregate system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation is pretty complicated but it basically pipes your response.  Try this:

```
model.aggregate([
    { $match: {
        $and: // match multiple
                {'user': 'bob'},
                {'deck.users': 'access_user' }
            }
    },
    {$project:{ // render each match in this format.  output an array. 
        "user": 1,
        "decks": 1
    }}
])
```

Try this if it doesn't work.  Comments added so you can understand each command. 
UPDATED.

```
model.aggregate(
    {$match: {'user':'bob'}},
    {$unwind: "$decks"},
    {$match: {"decks.users":"access_user"}})
```

Comment: Neither one works, your first one has an error in it. After `$and` in your missing '{', but it should be `$and: []` when I do the $and array it does not work, it returns all the decks and the book. Your second one is setup without problems but when I run it I get this error: `MongoError: unknown top level operator: $decks.users` Which is breaking after the `$unwind` Not sure why, I looked up the $unwind and it should be correct.

Comment: @Drew try the updated answer.  I removed $ from decks.users when looking for a match and got it working.   It will return all fields but you can append a "$project" filter after it and specify what to return.

Comment: That update that you provided has helped quiet a bit. Now it is only returning decks with a matching user! Now I tried to expand on it by appending `{ $match: { "book.users": "access_user"}}` to see if the book should be returned as well (this returned an empty array). In my example it should not, but, if a user has given "access_user" permission to read Book I need to check and return that or not return that. I also need to filter out the unwanted information 'pass, tokens, orgs, groups, users, _id, __v, etc.'

Comment: Do not worry about removing posts, I found out I can do that under `$project` by doing `orgs: 0, etc: 0`

Comment: So to bypass my check for the 'book' sub-document I simply rolled book into decks in my schema, since it is already a special deck. I simply marked `decks[0]` as this special deck. This makes the aggregate work perfectly, and the schema easier to read.